# Entity Framework: How can I join when all my tables have one controller and one remote service?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to connect to our middleware in the Azure cloud.

I can retrieve and send data to our servers just fine; until now: I am faced with joining a table.

Normally, when I would retrieve data I would do it like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserItem>?> GetItemByTelephone(string telephone)
{
    await InitializeAsync();

    try
    {
        return await _table.GetAsyncItems()
                           .Where(x => x.Telephone == telephone)
                           .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This would get an object from the User table, because I insert the `UserItem` (I think) and therefore it know what table to connect to.

Again, this is all working fine.

But now, as I want to "talk" to two tables, I can't use those remote services that are sort of bound to one table.

I have a migration `dbcontext` file, which I think is the way to start. How can I make a join against my database when all my services are bound to one table explicitly?

Or how can I simply run raw SQL against the database starting the line with `FROM TABLE XYZ` ?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no relationship between database tables and ASP.NET Controllers. You can pull from as many tables, even separate databases, as you like, in any Controller. It sounds to be more like you have some fundamental web-service design misunderstandings...

Comment: `catch { return null; }`  <-- **Don't do this** - you should log errors instead of swallowing them.

Comment: @Dai ok i might missunderstand how the controllers work. But there must be a way to just execute regular sql on my db- where would I do this? on the db context file? or on any of the controllers?

Comment: If you want to run raw SQL then use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` directly. If you want to use EF/`DbContext` to map raw SQL to classes/objects in your project [then there are a variety of techniques you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) - each with their own advantages... and caveats.